# How to reset the space between the label and the content of the item

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

As described above, I need to enlarge the space between the label and the content of the item of the section of Table of content (`\l@part` to be exact). and I typed the command `\setlength\labelsep{10em}`; but it does't work. See below, I want to enlarge the space marked in red rectangle

[image: the space marked in red rectangle]

[image]

The `.cls` file corresponding to the format of the above output

```
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%

  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax

    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%

    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%

    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%

    \begingroup

      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth

      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth

      {\leavevmode

       \large \bfseries #1

       \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern 1.5mu\cdot\mkern 1.5mu$}

       \hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par

       \nobreak

         \global\@nobreaktrue

         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%

    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

## A minimal example is provided:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{minitoc,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{I want to enlarge the space between the label and the content}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Just a sample section}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Explain}

\lipsum[3-8]

\section{Second}

\lipsum[9]

\chapter{Manual}

section{dddddn}

\subsection{cccExplain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you took the code in the linked question and added your own text to yield a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass{}` (`\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) and the appropriate packages that *illustrates* the problem . While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem, instead of spending time to first reproduce the problem.

Comment: So you are using `\documentclass{book}`? What about other packages involved in construction of the ToC (like [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) or [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc))? The main issue may not lie with `\l@part`, but with `\@part`.

Answer (score 3):

`\part` sets its ToC-entry within `\@part` (from [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls)):

```
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
```

To increase the space, use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch and adjust the `1em` space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum}
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@part}{1em}{2em}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{I want to enlarge the space between the label and the content}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Just a sample section}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Explain}

\lipsum[3-8]

\section{Second}

\lipsum[9]

\chapter{Manual}

\section{dddddn}

\subsection{cccExplain}

\end{document}
```

Above I've updated the space to `2em` (doubling it).

Comment: In fact, My thesis is based on book.cls, therefore all the modification should be done in \renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%, the example is used to express the meaning of place where the space is. so what should be done in book.cls in order to achieve the effect wanted.

Comment: I want to reset the space between the label and the chapter, section, subsection as well, so I want to know the feasible way.

Comment: Use a dedicated package like `titletoc`, (included in `titlesec`), that gives you full control on the formatting of the table of contents and has easy access documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
\def\@pardis{9em}% 
\def\@part[#1]#2{% 
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax 
\refstepcounter{part}% 
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\CTEXthepart\hspace{\@pardis}#1}% 
\else 
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}% 
\fi 
\@endpart}
```

give it a new definition

```
\def\@pardis{9em}%
```

you could set the whatever value you want, then it works!